# very basic - about client-server applications

Tags: android, client-server

I'm very new to this subject.
I try to build an application server that will interact with clients using Android.

Just before I dive into this field and learn everything, I want to know if there is a proof the design will work.

I build on the fact that the server I want to build can function as well as a client. 
For example If a user ask the application server for some data, that my server can POST as a client to another server to get the data to be processed and then handed to the user. Can this work?

again, sorry this is very basic, but I didn't find the specific answer to this and I wanted to make sure I'm not building something "in the air".

Comment: What exactly is your question ? I see none above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the things you want to do are achievable. It is no problem to let the server make requests to another API to provide the answers back to the client if you want to do sth like this:

Client:

```
myServer.getWeatherData();
```

MyServer

```
public List<WeatherData> getWeatherData() {
    //call to local weather station api
}
```